# invalid command-line parameter error while running the wikitude AR browser

Tags: android-emulator

> [2012-09-10 11:21:35 - com.wikitude.example.SimpleARBrowserActivity]
>   Android Launch!
>
> [2012-09-10 11:21:35 - com.wikitude.example.SimpleARBrowserActivity]
>   adb is running normally.
>
> [2012-09-10 11:21:35 - com.wikitude.example.SimpleARBrowserActivity]
>   Performing  com.wikitude.example.SimpleARBrowserActivity activity
>   launch
>
> [2012-09-10 11:21:35 - com.wikitude.example.SimpleARBrowserActivity]
>   Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD
>   'new'
>
> [2012-09-10 11:21:35 - com.wikitude.example.SimpleARBrowserActivity]
>   Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'new'
>
> *[2012-09-10 11:21:36 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4.
>
> [2012-09-10 11:21:36 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual
>   device named 'foo'.
>
> [2012-09-10 11:21:36 - Emulator] please use -help for more
>   information*

I downloaded the wikitude SDK from wikitude's site.  While running the wikitude browser, I got this error. Can someone please help me out?